# Choosing the correct bundle ID in iTunes Connect.

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, bundle

I am preparing to submit an app to the App Store and have come across the following form. In the past when I have done this incorrectly it caused me a lot of grief which I would like to avoid this time around.

[image]

It is giving me a few options to choose from, but I'm not sure which one is correct. I would assume there is a way to check my Xcode project to be sure that the bundle IDs match. More specifically I would think that the form below would correspond to my bundle id name

[image]

where if my app is called `AWESOMEAPP` the correct bundle to choose should read `EricBrotto.AWESOMEAPP` or `EricBrotto - *`. In fact I don't have either as an option. What I do have is `ericbrotto - *.` That said could I just choose this one and change my Bundle identifier to `ericbrotto.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`?

Any clarification would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the dollar signs, and enter explicitly com.ericbrotto.myawesomeapp into all of the provisioning portal, iTunes Connect and the Xcode Target Build settings.  Or use a wildcard just for the provisioning profile.

Comment: So create an explicit com.ericbrotto.awesomeapp App ID?